# How to replace colors with textures via Shaders in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-editor

I have a problem. I tried to search but I can't find what I want. 
I have a texture. This texture have a blue, green and black colors. They are masks, this is a face texture actually. I want to replace them like blue color will replace with my eyes texture in unity, green color will replace with face texture.. How can I write this shader? I searched but only I find color changing shaders :( Thanks..

Comment: Let me see if I'm understanding you correctly... You have a face texture with base colors and you want to use a Shader to target those base colors then replace them with other textures depending on those base colors?

Comment: @TimHunter Exactly :) Can you help me with that? I only found color replacing with colors..

Comment: I would highly recommend you consider using techniques other than a Shader for that then... Shader's can recognize the color of a pixel on a image, but it has no sense of scaling to line it up. That would require some custom logic code that could be better handled in another way. I would instead recommend switching the textures on the gameobject(s) instead. Have a reference to the "face" and "eyes" and change the texture on those instead of trying to resize and paint over them using a Shader. If you use a Shader there's going to be some unexpected behavior such as replacing the wrong areas.

Comment: @TimHunter Thats why I opened this post :/ Don't know how to do that looking for answer from someone I hope..

Comment: Ahh, then I have a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLOru6QQShM) here for you then! Just need to apply this same logic to a "face" and "eyes" object separately.

Comment: @TimHunter Oh sorry but it's not the thing I am looking for :( This video shows completely changes material texture. The thing I want is a Shader which is replace colors with textures. Example; Have a ona texture, in this texture mouth area is fully colored with blue, eyes area is fully colored with green. With shaders you can color with texture.. I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwQb1_yYMA0&t=193s but its not what I want. Its just changes color in colored area..

Comment: That's what I'm saying though... I recommend you use a texture swap instead of trying to target a color and replace it with a texture using a Shader. You're going to need to create a lot of logic to identify the locations and scale of your targeted color area to replace it with a texture using a Shader. You'd have an easier time of things if you just replace the texture on the object. Is there any particular reason you want it done through a Shader instead?

Comment: Please add your image texture.

Answer (score 1):

The way i interpret your question is that you want a shader where one texture serves as a mask, blending between 3 other textures. I'm assuming that this is for character customization, to stitch different pieces of face together.

In the fragment (or surf) function, sample your 3 textures and the mask:

```
fixed4 face = tex2D(_FaceTex, i.uv); // Green channel of the mask
fixed4 eyes = tex2D(_EyeTex, i.uv); // Blue channel of the mask
fixed4 mouth = tex2D(_MouthTex, i.uv); // No mask value (black)
fixed4 mask = tex2D(_MaskTex, i.uv);
```

Then, you need to blend them together using the mask. Let's assume that whatever black represents in the mask is the background color, and then we interpolate in the other textures.

```
fixed4 col = lerp(mouth, eyes, mask.b);
```

Then we can interpolate between the resulting color and our third value:

```
col = lerp(col, face, mask.g);
```

You could repeat this once again with the red channel, for a fourth texture. Of course, this assumes that you use pure red, green, or blue in the mask. There are ways to use a more specific color as key too, for instance you can use the absolute of the distance between the mask color and some reference color:

```
fixed4 eyeMaskColor = (0.5, 0.5, 1, 1);
half t = 1 - saturate(abs(length(mask - eyeMaskColor)));
```

In this case, `t` is the lerp factor you use to blend in the texture. The `saturate` function clamps the value in the range of [0, 1]. If the mask color is the same as eyeMaskColor, then the length of the vector between them is 0 and the statement evaluates to 1.